sensorless open loop estimation of rotor angle of pmsm
I am doing model based sensorless control of PMSM, to be more accurate I am doing an open-loop method of rotor angle estimation. So my project is to build a Simulink simulation in which I am calculating the rotor angle through flux and atan2 function. I am adding the equations I used in the model and also the model itself. I am doing this in perfect simulation environment, so I am using no inverter. The problem is that the estimated rotor angle is not the same with rotor angle I get from PMSM. I have no idea why estimated rotor angle is oscilating and why it is not the same with rotor angle from PMSM.
Ψ_α=∫〖u_α-i_αR〗
Ψ_β=∫〖u_β-i_βR〗
θ=atan2(Ψ_β-L_si_β,Ψ_α-L_si_α )



Lara -- I think you may need to provide more details to make this an understandable question.  Can you try explaining your issue more like you would explain it to somebody much less familiar with the problem?  FWIW, atan functions often have a problem called "phase wrapping".  It might help to do a search on "tangent unwrapping"

Thank you, I updated my question, and tangent unwraping did not help my problem.
